# Matisse GUI Builder's Built in Property Editors and java.awt.Image

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, matisse

I made a custom Swing component according to the JavaBean structure, and created a BeanInfo for it. When importing it to Matisse GUI Builder (NetBeans' built in GUI builder) my two custom properties (a float and a `java.awt.Image`) try to default edit with the "component chooser" which then displays "Custom editing of this property is not supported."

I can edit the float fine with the text field provided, but my Image I cannot do the same for. When I change the type of the image property to `javax.swing.Icon` I get the "Image Chooser" property editor by default. Is it possible to use this for my `java.awt.Image` property? If not, how would I go about making a custom property editor to do this for me?